# Search_tabs.json - Yammer API

Tags: api, yammer

Yammer search returns results because they are part of the replies and not in an intial message of the conversation. I want to retrive them using REST API and reading that search/search_tabs.json (not documented) can be used to understand why they are included in the search result. Does anyone know what input parameters it accepts ?

Comment: Can you share more about the use case and what you are trying to build? Do you only want to search the initial messages?

Comment: Sure - When using search.json, I'm noticing the search results which are not matching the search keyword. However some of the replies do have the search keyword. The result returned by search.json doesn't have any details about the replies. There is only this article [link] (https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/yammer-developer/can-anyone-tell-me-how-yammer-search-api-returns-results/m-p/33725)  that talks about using search_tabs.json however I'm not clear what should be the input parameters.